# In React, how to detect if the mouse is hovering an element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hover

```
const div_ref = useRef();

<div ref={div_ref} />
```

What are the properties of `div_ref` that I can use to find out if the mouse is hovering over `div_ref`?

Comment: Why are you bothering with a `ref`? Why can't you just add a `mouseover` listener to the element?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the onMouseEnter() listener in React to know when an element is being hovered with the mouse. For example, if you wanted to show a text in React when you hover over a heading (or any other element), you would use the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false); // initiate it at false

  return (
    <div>
      <h2
        onMouseEnter={() => setVisible(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setVisible(false)}>
        Move Mouse Towards Me
      </h2>
      {visible && ( // you can use "&&" since there is no else in this case
        <div>Text to show</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to get that information just for the useRef.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always that simple because the mouse enter and leave events are not symmetrical. For instance if you have the mouse hovered over element A and then you float another element B on top of element A you will (correctly) get a mouse leave for element A and a mouse enter for element B. However if you then hide element B you will get a mouse leave for B but no mouse enter for A